# Онлайн крестики-нолики, websocket

Tags: php, ajax, websocket

Хочу написать игру крестики-нолики (и шашки):

Суть такая: каждый пользователь сможет создать комнату, а другие смогут подключиться в созданную игру, таким образом образуется пара, и они могут играть в крестики-нолики.

Возникли такие вопросы: На чем лучше реализовать обмен данными (ходы игроков) через websocket или ajax?

И в тот момент когда образуется пара для игры, т.е. кто-то подключается в уже созданную игру, я для них создаю динамически отдельные 2 таблицы в БД, и в одной таблице будут хранится сообщения, которыми они обмениваются(в каждой комнате будет чат для общения соперников), и во второй таблице будут храниться координаты ходов, или матрица с позициями.

После завершения игры эти таблицы автоматически удаляются.

Скажите пожалуйста, это нормально? Сильная нагрузка на сервер из-за этого не будет? И какими методами вообще реализуют подобные задачи?

Comment: При создании данной игры ajax'ом, очень часто будет подвисать игра, не считая того, что вы еще собираетесь пихать туда чат. Так что ответ очевиден - PHP + WebSocket. Также могу посоветовать написать все на JS(NodeJS, клиентский JS и SocketIO), он в разы упростит написание игр, если, конечно, вы владеете данными технологиями.

Comment: @mix > *При создании данной игры ajax'ом, очень часто будет подвисать игра* - вы вот зря подаете это в качестве аксиомы (и зря ставите запятую там, где она не нужна)

Comment: > *я для них создаю динамически отдельные 2 таблицы в БД ... После завершения игры эти таблицы автоматически удаляются.* - Зачем?

Comment: @Etki это не аксиома, а горький опыт

Comment: @mix тем более зря экстраполируете единственный случай на всех остальных

Comment: @Etki вы сильно ошибаетесь, я высказываю свое мнение. И случай этот не единственный. А зря или не зря - решать каждому для себя.

Comment: ajax для таких целей - это глупая, абсолютно пустая нагрузка на сервер, и действительно будут "подвисания", пусть и минимальные, но затянут игру. единственно php не очень расчитан для этих целей. насчет таблиц  -это по мере необходимости, ведь захочется проводить соревнования , сравнивать рейтинги, смотреть историю.

Comment: Да откуда вы вообще подвисания взяли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Возникли такие вопросы: На чем лучше реализовать обмен данными (ходы игроков) через websocket или ajax?

Строго говоря, websocket-подключения создавались для динамичных случаев вроде этого, и, конечно, в идеале нужно использовать именно их. Однако у PHP есть ряд проблем с их имплементацией (PHP сам по себе не очень заточен под такие вещи, и, к тому же, из-за отсутствия многопточности либо нагружается только одно ядро, либо надо следить за количеством процессов, ставить балансировщик нагрузки и ставить message broker для распространения application-wide событий), поэтому не будет ничего страшного, если этот функционал будет реализован на срабатывающем раз в секунду ajax-запросе.

> я для них создаю динамически отдельные 2 таблицы в БД, и в одной таблице будут хранится сообщения, которыми они обмениваются(в каждой комнате будет чат для общения соперников), и во второй таблице будут храниться координаты ходов, или матрица с позициями.
>
> После завершения игры эти таблицы автоматически удаляются.

Вот это действительно абсолютно ненужные и противоречащие красивой организации действия. Нужно просто создать две постоянные таблицы, в которых сохранять все данные с идентификатором комнаты, по которому и производить выборку. Т.е. у каждого хода и сообщения есть дополнительное поле `room_id`, по которому ищутся все результаты.

> Скажите пожалуйста, это нормально? Сильная нагрузка на сервер из-за этого не будет? И какими методами вообще реализуют подобные задачи?

Нагрузка определяется в основном количеством пользователей, и пока у вас не самый топовый сервак, всегда можно решить проблему сервером уровня выше. В идеале это должно быть многопоточное приложение, равномерно нагружающее все ядра процессора и работающее с клиентом через вебсокеты, на данном этапе я бы не заморачивался и делал все через ajax. Этот способ обычно не очень толерируется сообществом (если быть точным, то обычно в виду имеется long polling, я же предлагаю регулярно оббивать сервер запросами), но на самом деле ничего квазистрашного в нем нет.

Comment: Спасибо большое,

А как быть с чатом в каждой комнате?
Ведь это много ненужный информации.. зачем нам лишний раз держать в бд сообщения после завершения игры.. 

Хотя можно будет после игры их из общей таблицы удалять по room_id..

А как вы думаете будет лучше хранить координаты шашек?

Я думаю, как образуется пара, в таблицу добавиться поле `pos`(VARCHAR), в котором будет матрица 8x8, и числовые элементы матрицы, которые будут обозначить, фишки, цвет поля, дамка или обычная шашка .. И при последующих запросах от клиентов, после каждого хода, будет изменяться матрица?